# FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/audio/assets/Sound3.mp3)

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, assets

I want to play an audio as the app background music(without button click/autoplay). The code seen like no problem, but cant display.Did I do anything wrong with the code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame_audio/flame_audio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(GameWidget(game: Audio()));
}

class Audio extends FlameGame with TapDetector {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void onTapUp(TapUpInfo) {
    FlameAudio.bgm.play('assets/Sound3.mp3');
  }
}
```

> pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - assets/Sound3.mp3
```

[The Error Show in C:\flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\services\asset_bundle.dart][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p383i.png

Comment: i have fix it!

pubspec.yaml

assets:
    - assets/Sound3.mp3    

In main.dart file,  
@override
  void onTapUp(TapUpInfo) {
    FlameAudio.bgm.play('assets/Sound3.mp3');
  }   *Create an audio foulder in the assets dir and inset Sound3.mp3 into the audio foulder*

Answer (score 0):

```
const AssetImage('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons');
```

Assets used by the package (or plugin) itself should also be fetched using the package argument.

line: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images